# Why does not `import lib.reload()` work for `itertools.count`?

Tags: python, import, python-itertools, python-importlib

I want to reload `itertools` to reload function `count`. Here is what I got from my Mac(M1-air).

```
import itertools
for x in itertools.count(3,2):
  if x>30:
    break
  print(x) 
# works fine
# 3 5 7 9 11 13 15 17 19 21 23 25 27 29 
itertools.count = 10
print(itertools.count) # 10

import importlib
importlib.reload(itertools)
print(itertools.count) # 10
```

In my opinion, the last result `10` should be changed to original `count` function because I reloaded `itertools` with `import lib.reload(itertools)`.

Following the link from one of the comments, now I see `itertools` is a built-in package and `importlib.reload()` does not apply to built-in packages. Then, how can I reload a built-in package?

It is quite natural to think of a way to revert something I did for several reasons. (and it is also of theoretical interest searching for symmetry if you knew what I mean) For example, `git revert`... Of course I can always set aside a variable and use it later

```
count = itertools.count

itertools.count = 10

# then later
itertools.count = count
```

Comment: There are various caveats in https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.reload that probably apply here.

Comment: It seems like that `itertools` is a built-in package and that the reason. Then how can I reload a built-in package?

Comment: Why do you think you need to? In this case it's because you've replaced one of its attributes, so... don't do that.

Comment: So, you want the second `print(itertools.count)` to raise an `AttributeError: module 'itertools' has no attribute 'count'`?

Comment: No second print would print `itertools.count` which is the same as the result of `print(itertools.count)` before the modification

Comment: That is what happens when I run your code.

Comment: You mean the first code block? Strange. It is what I got. I got `10`

Comment: `print(itertools.count)` prints `10` in both places.

Answer (score 0):

Simply "Do not do it" does not help anyone :(
Even `goto` has a few advocates(including the founder of linux as far as I remember).

Here is what I came up with. Just delete the module and reload using `import`.

```
import itertools
count = itertools.count

itertools.count = 10

print(itertools.count) # 10

import sys

del sys.modules['itertools']
del itertools

import itertools

print(itertools.count) # itertools.count
```