# How to reload **builtin** module sys in python?

Tags: python, import, sys

This is a theoretical or experimental question.
I am searching for generality here. "Does a method apply to every possible appliable object?"

I recently asked about how to reload builtin-modules.
Here is the result so far : [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70529940/why-does-not-import-lib-reload-work-for-itertools-count?noredirect=1#comment124676452_70529940)

As far as I know, we need to delete `sys.modules['package_name']` and `package_name`.

Does this method apply to all the other built-in library?

Well maybe. But I tried to delete `sys` and reload it, I failed. It seems that for `import`ing we need `sys` package because `import` searchs `sys.modules`.

So my question is how can i reload the built-in package `sys`? I wont accept any answer like "Don't do it". I know that I won't have a chance to use this or it's much faster just to restart python but I might understand more about python searching for this answer, so is there any chance to reloading `sys`?

Comment: does `importlib.reload(sys)` not work?

Comment: generally `importlib.reload()` does not work for built-in packages

Comment: almost certainly, removing `sys` is going to lead to all sorts of strange behavior, it s a module that is used by the runtime itself, as you noted, the `import` system itself uses `sys`